# Rails Composer doesn't work on Windows. SSL Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssl

I have RailsInstaller with Ruby 2.0 and Rails 4.0. I create an app with this:

```
$ rails new myapp -m https://raw.github.com/RailsApps/rails-composer/master/composer.rb
```

Then i got this:

```
apply  https://raw.github.com/RailsApps/rails-composer/master/composer.rb
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:918:in `connect': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:918:in `block in connect'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/timeout.rb:52:in `timeout'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:918:in `connect'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:862:in `do_start'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:851:in `start'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/open-uri.rb:313:in `open_http'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/open-uri.rb:708:in `buffer_open'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/open-uri.rb:210:in `block in open_loop'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/open-uri.rb:208:in `catch'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/open-uri.rb:208:in `open_loop'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/open-uri.rb:149:in `open_uri'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/open-uri.rb:688:in `open'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/open-uri.rb:34:in `open'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor/actions.rb:216:in `apply'
```

What is this? 
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download the cacert.pem file from [here](http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem). Save this file to C:\RailsInstaller\cacert.pem.

Now make ruby aware of your certificate authority bundle by setting SSL_CERT_FILE. To set this in your current command prompt session, type:

```
  $  set SSL_CERT_FILE=C:\RailsInstaller\cacert.pem
```

That's all. Works fine!